# Compiling Squid proxy for Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, proxy, mingw-w64, squid

As mentioned on the page- https://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/Windows, the pre-built binary packages are available for Squid 3.3 and 4. However, the current stable version of Squid is 5 with versions 6 and 7 already under development.

Given that pre-built packages are not readily available for Windows, I am hoping to compile version 5/6/7 for Windows. However, the instructions provided here- https://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/Windows#compiling are not user friendly and sort of incomplete.

Does anyone have any experience in compiling Squid for Windows? If so, can you please share instructions for the same?